# Parse date/time value from react-datetime

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs

I'm using `react-datetime` to render a calendar to user for date/time selection. How can I get the parse the value stored in state and turn it into a readable date so I can render that elsewhere in my UI.

I sent `date` in a post request and the value looks like: `2018-10-26T18:15:47.608Z`. When I try to render that time in a table it gets stripped to this value `1540577747608`. I want to display the zulu time for now.

```
      this.state = {
         date: new Date()
      }

      dateChange = date => this.setState({ date });

      render() {
      return (
            <div>
              <label>Choose a start date/time:</label>
              <Datetime
                onChange={this.dateChange}
                value={this.state.date}
                input={false}
                isValidDate={validDate}
                open={true}
                utc={false}
                onClickDay={value => alert("day" + value + "clicked")}
              />
            </div>
          </div>
```

In a different component where I want to render the date,
the value is being retrieved from an api call and being stored 
`formatDate: response.data.data.date`

Then, I'm rendering in a table: `<td key={schedule.formatDate}>{schedule.formatDate}</td>`

Answer (score 1):

`Date` does not have easy method for time formatting.
If you want to display the UTC time - or zulu time - you must use the dedicated methods to access hours, minutes and seconds and format them manually.
For example, the following displayes the UTC hours and minutes:

```
`${event.getUTCHours()}h${event.getUTCMinutes()}`
```